# How to find the file system type in python

Tags: python, windows, macos, filesystems

I'm looking for a way in python to find out which type of file system is being used for a given path. I'm wanting to do this in a cross platform way. On linux I could just grab the output of `df -T` but that won't work on OSX or windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the hint -- different platforms are actually different.

Use `lsvfs` on Mac OS X and those Linux that support it.

Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on Windows.

Use an if-statement to decide.

Answer (score -1):

[This is the Windows API you might want to call.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo(v=VS.100).aspx) [This should be a good start for the OS X api you are looking for, instead.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/Articles/FileInfo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009068-SW1)

Answer (score -2):

os.popen('/sbin/fdisk -l /dev/sda') on Linux