# Determine if a file is on an NTFS filesystem

Tags: python, windows, ntfs

Is there a Windows API for determining if a certain file (path) is on an NTFS filesystem?

If this can be somehow inferred from an existing Python API, all the better.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800798/how-to-find-the-file-system-type-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know how to do it in Python, but I assume that invoking C functions will be easy.

So in C open file handle bu [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you'll retrieve a handle to such file. Then call [GetVolumeInformationByHandleW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964920%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and check the lpFileSystemNameBuffer variable for "ntfs" string.

Comment: uh, just noticed the minimum required Windows version on this is Vista

Comment: In the earlier versions you can use the GetVolumeInformation function as the reparse points were not supported by ntfs yet.

Comment: yeah, problem is it requires a root path which is less convenient, thanks though.

Comment: Then you can step one layer lower and use ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile from ntdll.dll, which is present in XP+. GetVolumeInformationByHandleW is just forward to this function. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567070%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In python you can do:

```
import win32api
t = win32api.GetVolumeInformation(path)
print t[-1]
```

which will print `ntfs` if the path is on that filesystem type

(based on Yakeen's answer but also untested as i don't have a windows machine)

Comment: That's it, but this way it won't work on reparse points (like mounted volumes as directories), that's why working over file handle is safer.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your needs, you can use GetFileAttributes and check ntfs File Attribute Constants.

Comment: What exactly do you mean Mox? All of them are present just in special cases.

Comment: I meant, some attributes like FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED or FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE are only available on a NTFS volume. These attributes can be used as hint to determine if a file is on an NTFS filesystem.