# how do I know if a "path" is located in a FAT32 partition?

Tags: python, linux

is there any library or function that tells me the partition's type for a specific "path" in python??

or how can I accomplish that with any other approach?

thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the mountpoint a file resides on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453602/how-to-find-the-mountpoint-a-file-resides-on)

Comment: It's related, but this question has an additional element (finding the partition type) that the original question did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to find the file system type in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800798/how-to-find-the-file-system-type-in-python) also seems relevant.

Here's what I came up with:

```
import subprocess
import os

def is_filesys_fat32(path):

    try:
        subprocess.check_call(['df', '--type=fat32', path], stdout=os.devnull)
    except:
        return False

    return True
```

Assuming you're running linux (as the tag mentions), and that you're only searching for existence of the type, not getting the type (use a regex on `subprocess.check_output()` using the same command?).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, in my previous answer, I thought you need windows, however, I believe I found a way in Linux.

Try this:

By using subprocess on this command `df -T /users/f/foo/file.txt` , you can get the results you need.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["df -T %s"] % path, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

Sample output:

```
Filesystem    Type   1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5     ext4   472439072 146088944 302351616  33% /
```