# Determining the filesystem type from a path in Python

Tags: python, filesystems

Is there any *portable* way in Python (2.*) to obtain the filesystem type of the device containing a given path? For instance, something like:

```
>>> get_fs_type("/foo/bar")
'vfat'
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2802104/752261) may help.

Comment: not sure, but https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil may do it

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution. I tried to make it more generic for cases where /var/lib is a different partition. Some ugliness crept in the code as windows always has the separator at the end of the mountpoint, while this is omitted in linux. Which means testing them both

```
import psutil, os
def printparts():
    for part in psutil.disk_partitions():
        print part
def get_fs_type(path):
    partition = {}
    for part in psutil.disk_partitions():
        partition[part.mountpoint] = (part.fstype, part.device)
    if path in partition:
        return partition[path]
    splitpath = path.split(os.sep)  
    for i in xrange(len(splitpath),0,-1):
        path = os.sep.join(splitpath[:i]) + os.sep
        if path in partition:
            return partition[path]
        path = os.sep.join(splitpath[:i])
        if path in partition:
            return partition[path]
    return ("unkown","none")

printparts()

for test in ["/", "/home", "/var", "/var/lib", "C:\\", "C:\\User", "D:\\"]:
    print "%s\t%s" %(test, get_fs_type(test))
```

On windows:

```
python test.py
sdiskpart(device='C:\\', mountpoint='C:\\', fstype='NTFS', opts='rw,fixed')
sdiskpart(device='D:\\', mountpoint='D:\\', fstype='NTFS', opts='rw,fixed')
sdiskpart(device='E:\\', mountpoint='E:\\', fstype='NTFS', opts='rw,fixed')
sdiskpart(device='F:\\', mountpoint='F:\\', fstype='', opts='cdrom')
sdiskpart(device='G:\\', mountpoint='G:\\', fstype='', opts='cdrom')
/       ('unkown', 'none')
/home   ('unkown', 'none')
/var    ('unkown', 'none')
/var/lib        ('unkown', 'none')
C:\     ('NTFS', 'C:\\')
C:\User ('NTFS', 'C:\\')
D:\     ('NTFS', 'D:\\')
```

On linux:

```
python test.py
partition(device='/dev/cciss/c0d0p1', mountpoint='/', fstype='ext4', opts='rw,errors=remount-ro')
partition(device='/dev/cciss/c0d1p3', mountpoint='/home', fstype='ext4', opts='rw')
partition(device='/dev/cciss/c0d1p2', mountpoint='/var', fstype='ext4', opts='rw')
/       ('ext4', '/dev/cciss/c0d0p1')
/home   ('ext4', '/dev/cciss/c0d1p3')
/var    ('ext4', '/dev/cciss/c0d1p2')
/var/lib        ('ext4', '/dev/cciss/c0d1p2')
C:\     ('unkown', 'none')
C:\User ('unkown', 'none')
D:\     ('unkown', 'none')
```

Comment: Best answer indeed, you could have avoided to check improper mountpoint by using the platform module as in: https://docs.python.org/2/library/platform.html

Not quite important be could save execution time :D

Comment: Use `psutil.disk_partitions(all=True)` if you want to include NFS and other non-local-block-device mounts.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to user3012759's comment, here's a solution (certainly improvable upon but nonetheless working):

```
import psutil

def get_fs_type(mypath):
    root_type = ""
    for part in psutil.disk_partitions():
        if part.mountpoint == '/':
            root_type = part.fstype
            continue

        if mypath.startswith(part.mountpoint):
            return part.fstype

    return root_type
```

A separate treatment was needed for "/" under GNU/Linux, since all (absolute) paths start with that.

Here's an example of the code "in action" (GNU/Linux):

```
>>> get_fs_type("/tmp")
'ext4'
>>> get_fs_type("/media/WALKMAN")
'vfat'
```

And another one under Windows (XP if it matters):

```
>>> get_fs_type("C:\\")  # careful: "C:" will yield ''
'NTFS'
```

Comment: This would not work because you may have nested mounts like this: / - root mount; /usr - other type; /usr/tmp - other type; code provided in this answer will return type of /usr for file in /usr/tmp/myfile.

Comment: `psutil` is a huge import! Is there  a way to limit the psutil import with `import XXX from psutil`?

Comment: The only useful `psutil` function for this specific case is `disk_partitions`, so yes: `from psutil import disk_partitions`.

Comment: Use `psutil.disk_partitions(all=True)` if you want to include NFS and other non-local-block-device mounts.

Answer (score 1):

```
import psutil

def get_fs_type(path):
    bestMatch = ""
    fsType = ""
    for part in psutil.disk_partitions():
        if mypath.startswith(part.mountpoint) and len(bestMatch) < len(part.mountpoint):
            fsType = part.fstype
            bestMatch = part.mountpoint
    return fsType
```

Comment: How is this different from the other answers?

Comment: Code complexity different and it would actually work in all cases - see descrition on the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

for linux, installing the `stat` command, I used

```
P = subprocess.run(['stat', '-f', '-c', '%T', path],
                    capture_output=True, text=True)
fstype = P.stdout.strip().lower()
```

Edit: adding text=True will return the result as a `str` otherwise it will be `bytes`. Also you may want to check that `P.returncode == 0`. Moreover, you may want to use `functools.cache` to cache results, if this code is called frequently

Answer (score -1):

For anyone prioritizing concision here's a slightly shorter version of gena2x's answer:

```
def get_fs_type(path):
    path_matching_fstypes_mountpoints = [
        part for part in disk_partitions() 
        if str(path.resolve()).startswith(part.mountpoint)
    ]
    return sorted(path_matching_fstypes_mountpoints, key=lambda x: len(x.mountpoint))[-1].fstype
```